# Rails 6: Can't delete nested model. Random Insert statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, destroy, ruby-on-rails-6, accepts-nested-attributes

I using Rails 6 with Postgres and having issues deleting a nested model. 
A random insert statement gets generated after the association has been deleted.

Let me explain my set up.

Migrations

```
class CreateEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :entries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Cards < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :cards do |t|
      t.string :card_number
      t.belongs_to :entry, null: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Models

```
class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :card, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :card, allow_destroy: true
end

class Card < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entry
end
```

Controller

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_entry

    def update
       @entry.update(entry_params)
    end

    def set_entry
       @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
    end

    def entry_params
      params.require(:entry).permit(:name,
        card_attributes: [:id, :card_number, :_destroy]
      )
    end
end
```

Request Params

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"CQ...Ucw==", "entry"=>{"card_attributes"=>{"_destroy"=>"true"}}, "id"=>"1"}
```

These are the logs

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN

ConcessionCard Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "cards".* FROM "cards" WHERE "cards"."entry_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["entry_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Card Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "cards" WHERE "cards"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]

Card Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "cards" ("entry_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["entry_id", 1], ["created_at", "2019-09-06 13:50:41.100718"], ["updated_at", "2019-09-06 13:50:41.100718"]]

(0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Why is insert being generated after the delete call? It's not even a rollback.

Note: I have tried both null:true and null:false in the Cards belongs_to migration. I also tried setting optional:true in the belongs_to :entry statement in the Card model

Comment: Please help, I am going crazy.

Comment: Do you have some code on the Entry model that sets the associated Card? Can you try replacing the `update` call with `@entry.attributes = ...; @entry.save`? you could use byebug or pry rails to inspect the object before calling `save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you include an `id` in `card_attributes` then Rails sees this as a new record, so it just replaces the `has_one` with a newly created `Card` for you (which because of your `dependent: :destroy` option deletes the existing associated `Card`).

Best to use a `form.fields_for :card` block in your form partial/view, which will automatically add the hidden `id` tag for an existing Card.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really appreciate your help. The delete operation doesn't get performed if I include the card id in the card attributes. Here are the params: "entry"=>{"card_attributes"=>{"id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"true"}}. However, if the card id is excluded from the card attributes, then the delete operated gets performed followed by the insert operation as you have suggested.

Comment: Thank you, Sir Smathy. That solved it. I would love to buy you a beer. Please let me know how.